# How to freeze a service for sometime in nsis?

Tags: nsis

My requirement is to freeze a servise group for around a minute(60 secs). How can I do that in nsis?
 I guess it would be something like this:
hagrp -value Service Frozen...

Comment: Do you want to execute hagrp or what?

Comment: Yes Anders... Want to execute hagrp and freeze the service for sometime

Comment: The freeze part of the question is a little confusing because it has nothing to do with NSIS and I thought you wanted to pause a Windows service at first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute applications with `Exec`/`ExecWait`:

```
Exec '"$instdir\myapp.exe" /param1 "par am2" /param3'
```

If you want to execute a console application without showing the console window then you have to use one of he exec plugins: [nsExec](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsExec/nsExec.txt), [ExecDos](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in)
or [ExecCmd](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecCmd_plug-in).

**Edit:**

There are [several plugins and scripts](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_do_I_start/stop/create/remove/check_a_service) to choose from if you want to manipulate a Windows service...

Comment: Ok please let me know how can i pause windows service and that helps me in using it for my install part

Comment: Make up your mind, do you want to execute some application or pause a service?